# How To Import .rdc File Into Blender

Tags: add-on, import

I've downloaded the mesh model importer addon version 0.3.3
installed it on various versions of blender
but when I try and import model as .rdc file I get this error

See photo

Any ideas what to do?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was able to fix it by changing the versions of each program. Below is the cocktail of versions I used:

- Blender: **2.91.0**
- Renderdoc: **1.10**
- MapsModelsImporter: **0.3.5**